# How to capture user submitted attribute values when ActiveRecord validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there an elegant way to call a method when a **specific** ActiveRecord validation fails?  I'm envisioning something like...

validates :email_address, :uniqueness => true, **:when_fail => :call_method**

I have a roundabout way of calling the method when the validation fails involving code in my controller, but I'm looking for something more straight-forward within the model.  I can't find any relevant examples online.

EDITED out other details to focus on the question.

Comment: Why are you not using the session instead of cookies? You could create an session[:new_users] and store the user-ids..if a new user wants to register, check the email against the session and the database..

Comment: @Mattherick - I edited my post to focus in on my question. I have more to learn about sessions and cookies, but that's for later.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hmm but that only allows a user to sign up and sign in with one computer. And btw the cookie can be hacked or copied. Why do you create such an authentication system? I would recommend using an existing system like devise. I understand your question, but I think you are on the completely wrong road..hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this in model?

```
Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_validation do
    self.my_method unless self.errors.empty?
  end
end
```

For specific validation you can use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-5B-5D.